# jquery animation div width=0 not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-animate

I have divs on my page as below;

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="header">
    </div>
    <div id="sidebar">
        <div id="switch"></div>
        <div id="list"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="viewer"></div>
    <div id="footer">
    </div>
</div>
```

div `switch` is a button meant to shrink `sidebar` and to stretch`viewer`. I want the `sidebar` to shrink completely to the left and to stretch `viewer` to the remaining space. But still I am getting a 5px wide gap. You can have a look at my fiddle [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/blasteralfred/XFXfE/). How can I solve this??

Thanks in advance...`:)`

blasteralfred

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line too your css:

```
#list {padding-left: 0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the padding-left in #list and the whitespace is gone.